# android: displaying radio buttons when starting application

Tags: android, menu, radio-button

I have an application in android that shows a list of videos.. However, the list can be stored either in internal storage or in external storage. What I want is that when the application starts, I want two radio buttons and a save button. The radio buttons should ask the user about whether they want to select internal storage or external storage.. And the save button should save the settings. Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for anything along the lines of user-controlled settings or configurations you would like to save.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have an opening activity (that could be made to look like a dialog if you so choose) that presents the option to the user and then passes that option to the next activity that actually runs the program.

Comment: thts a good idea but actually I don't want to make it as a starting activity because i'll only take it for the first time when the application is run. After that, this option selected by the user will be saved and won't be displayed.. Okay, can you guide me about how to make these radio buttons with a save button for saving the options?

Comment: So set in SharedPreferences to check if a flag is true. If it is not then it is the first time running and present the option activity. otherwise load the preference selected and run the regular program